# How can I change the background music from one scene to another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

There are **only two scenes** in my game.
The first is the menu and the second is the game.
In the second scene I added background music and I made sure that when reloading the scene the music did not interrupt, but this means that when returning to the menu the music continues overlapping that of the menu.

Can you give me any solutions please? Thank you!

This is the code to make the music continue with the scene reloads:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackgroundMusic : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static BackgroundMusic backgroundMusic;
    
    void Awake()
    {
    
       if (backgroundMusic == null)
        {
            backgroundMusic = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(backgroundMusic);
            Debug.Log(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the same game object with the `BackgroundMusic` script on both of the scenes. Since you implemented the singleton pattern, this will ensure that only 1 music player will ever play at one time.

Now, subscribe to `SceneManager.sceneLoaded` so that you can change the music based on the scene, like so:

```cs
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackgroundMusic : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static BackgroundMusic backgroundMusic;

    void Awake() 
    { 
        // Keep singleton pattern implementation here 
        SceneManager.onSceneLoaded += SwitchMusic;
    }

    void SwitchMusic()
    {
        // Logic to change music tracks here.
        // You could have an array of AudioClip and index 
        // that array by the scene's build index, for instance.

        // You can also just check if scenes actually changed, and if not,
        // you can make the music just continue without changing.
    }
}
```

Let me know in the comments if you have any questions.

Comment: ```SceneManager.onSceneLoaded``` give me an error : SceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'onSceneLoaded'

Comment: Sorry, it's `sceneLoaded`, not `onSceneLoaded`. ([documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html))

Comment: Ok, now it works. Can you show me how change music track by script?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to do. If you're planning to only have 2 scenes in your entire game, I would just switch between 2 `AudioClip`s, but if you want to expand later and have more than 2 scenes, you might want to include functionality to not switch the music if the scene transition was between 2 scenes that are supposed to have the same music track playing in the background.
In any case, you should probably make a new question for that (I'll keep an eye out on your profile to see if you posted a new question), and if my answer worked, accepting/upvoting it would be appreciated.